# How can I tell if a PTAC unit is drawing outside air when heating?

Tags: hvac

I was attempting to research if a PTAC unit installed was drawing in outside air when in in heat mode.  Doing some cursory research, I have found articles that claim PTAC units both do and do not bring in outside air.  I am also having trouble tracking down the specific model number installed to see if I can find a manual or technical reference.

In general, do PTAC units draw in outside air when in heat mode, or do they just recirculate indoor air?  If the answer is 'it depends,' is there some easy way to verify what it is doing if you do not have access to the outside of the unit?

Comment: All HVAC only recirculate

Comment: @Magaman I believe at least some bring in outside air?  From a marketing blurb on a "Friedrich PTAC": Friedrich’s FreshAire® PTAC system helps achieve ASHRAE 62.1-2013 requirements, and brings up to 52 CFM of conditioned, MERV 8 filtered, outside air into the space.